# using the swaRm package to identify GPS location errors

Tags: r, gps, swarm

I am using the swaRm package to analyse decimal degree GPS data in order to find location errors (https://rpubs.com/sjmgarnier/swaRm).

Firstly I have created an R6 object from my data frame to create a trajectory table

```
F108traj<-makeTraj(x = F108$Longitude, y = F108$Latitude, id = "01", 
                   date = F108$Date, time = F108$Time, 
                   date.format = "dmy", time.format = "hms",
                   geo = TRUE)
```

Then I have used the code to search for potential location errors

```
loc_err <- findLocErr(F108traj)
loc_err
```

which then returns this:

```
integer(0)
```

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what this means? I find it very hard to believe that there are no location errors as I have 55657 GPS fixes!

Here is a small section of the data:

```
Date         Time       Latitude     Longitude
12/06/2017   12:25:00   50.774715   -3.932923
12/06/2017   12:25:01   50.774742   -3.932912
12/06/2017   12:25:02   50.774773   -3.932896
12/06/2017   12:25:04   50.774792   -3.932908
12/06/2017   12:25:05   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:06   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:07   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:08   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:10   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:11   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:12   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:14   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:15   50.774803   -3.932924
12/06/2017   12:25:16   50.774803   -3.932924
```

I should also mention that fixes were recorded every second, but there are instances where the GPS has failed

Comment: What is the `F108traj` object?

Comment: @amonk this is just the name of my trajectory table

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us just a portion of data? The devil in the details lies...

Comment: @amonk have added a snippet

Comment: how is F108traj assosiated with the data? I mean is is a data.frame/data.table? or a swarm object?

Comment: the `swarm` flag of the question is redundant to your case.

Comment: @amonk according to the RPubs swaRm descriptor, it's a R6 object, so neither data.frame/data.table.

Comment: Just include how you associate the F108traj  with the rest of the data (E.g `F108traj <-makeTraj(...)`?)

Comment: @amonk have included it above

Comment: Try to share the `dput(F108)` instead of the simple copy paste * small section* . In this way it will be reproducible by the rest of us